# Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache()

Tags: cache, apc

for some reason we need to clear **APC Opcode cache**

so i am adding below lines at the end of index.php file

```
apc_clear_cache();
apc_clear_cache('user');
```

after i run the index.php file from browser,

than i am getting following error at the end of the frontend and backend :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache() in /var/www/html/site/index.php on line 92
```

so is there any way to clear APC cache through index.php file or how we can do this from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Magento issue, it means that your PHP is not supporting that method.

You probably do not have APC module installed.

Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php