# Pressing "Flush magento cache" button in admin panel leads to "Currently unable to handle this request"

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, caching

Please help me to understand the issue if my question is not related to "magento.stachexchange". Everything is fine in my magento installation but this button

```
Pressing “Flush Magento cache” button in admin panel leads to “Currently unable to handle this request”
```

Where should I look for the cause or the problem? Is it permission issue?

Comment: Are you getting this error from magento? or is it an error message from the webserver? a screenshot would be best to identify this.

Comment: in root of site, `index.php` file will be there,  take backup of that file & uncommnet this line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  and check what error its showing after that..... also please check var/logs folder errors

Comment: @Baby in Magento, does it show the error in front-end! I do not dare do it now, I have to leave it for night time...

Comment: @Zinat mostly i think it will show in backend, but i am not sure about it . if it is live site , you can create one demo/staging site and check , if not possible you can check in night time only. atleast check var/logs now.....

Comment: @Nidheesh, after pressing the button it seems jumping out from admin panel and displaying this message in browser

Comment: @Zinat is any `500 error` also try conatcting hosting team also in parallel.....

Comment: @Baby in Magento, sure I'll do as you said. I'll post the result then, hope hearing from you again. Thanks

Comment: @BabyinMagento, hosting team! what could be wrong there? we have another installation which is fine, and I suppose there are identical configuration.

Comment: @Zinat i'm not sure it is from hosting team , but there may be chances.... if their is no pressure to find solution soon, you can try from magento side and than you can contact them.....

Comment: @Zinat if you have a different log file in "/var/logs/[apache or nginx]/ for your domain, copy the last few lines after accessing the same url.

Comment: @Nidheesh, [error] 13578#0: *1680973 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache() in /path/app/code/community/Buric/Apc/Model/Observer.php on line 13" while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.106.222.157, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /index.php/admin/cache/flushSystem/key/a2a654d657aafaa937e8acdfba5540af/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mydomain", referrer: "http://mydomain/index.php/admin/cache/index/key/c4df04ee1faa0cbc050eda65ed8c5446/"

Comment: @Nidheesh, OMG, what is this?

Comment: Looks like the APC module wasn't enabled in PHP or not installed. So magento is unable to flush the cache from APC. The server team should be able to help you to do this.

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102334/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-apc-clear-cache

Comment: @Nidheesh, I'll check that, but consider that in other installation we do not have any issue with "Flushing cache" button. That makes me more wonder...

Comment: @Nidheesh, could be the issue from "Buric" extension?

Comment: @Zinat You can disable that extension and try, but the other installation is on the same server?

Comment: @Nidheesh, yes in same server. I'll give it a try tonight. Thanks for following up my matter. Hope hearing from you if I did not figure it out. I'll keep here updated tomorrow.

Comment: @Nidheesh, You are right, APC module is not enabled in PHP. If you have it as answer I'll accept it. Thaaaaaaaaaaaanks a looooooot

Comment: will add it as answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45748/discussion-between-nidheesh-and-zinat).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45749/discussion-on-question-by-zinat-pressing-flush-magento-cache-button-in-admin-p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be different reasons for this issue. The best way to figure out the issue is "check your webserver log" which will be "/var/logs/[apache or nginx]/[the log file name configured in virtual host]".

In this case, the error message is:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_clear_cache() in /path/app/code/community/Buric/Apc/Model/Observer.php on line 13" while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.106.222.157, server: www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /index.php/admin/cache/flushSystem/key/a2a654d657aafaa937e8a‌​cdfba5540af/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mydomain", referrer:
```

Means, the magento plugin Buric_Apc is unable to perform the apc cache flush which is because, the APC module is not enabled in php or not installed on server